# get the bytes of the file for Scanner - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, file

I need help to get the bytes of a file in a textbox. It's for an antivirus scanner.

Well the scanner is Hexadecimal, but I have been told to convert the HEX string to Bytes and compare it with the Bytes of the file. 
**My question is: How do I get the Bytes from the file?**

**Could you help me with an example?**

Well this is what I tried to do to get the bytes:

```
 ' Opendia IS OPENFILEDIALOG
    Dim result As DialogResult = OpenDia.ShowDialog()

    ' Test result.
    If result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

        ' Get the file name.
        Dim path As String = OpenDia.FileName
        Try

            Dim bytes As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes(path)
            'I try to show the Bytes of the file in the textbox

            TextBox1.Text = bytes.Length

        Catch ex As Exception

            MsgBox(ex.Message)

        End Try
    End If
```

Post where is the Scanner : [Scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52766391/binary-file-scanner)

Comment: If you need to compare information, use byte. If you need to display information, then you have no choice but to use strings. I suggest you use string builder.

Comment: Hexadecimal usually refers to the *representation* of the bytes, in the same sense as the ["This Is Not a Pipe"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Treachery_of_Images) painting. You already have the bytes, in the array named `bytes`.

Comment: If you want to show a small part of the start of the array `bytes` for visual effect, you could use `TextBox1.Text = String.Join(" ", bytes.Take(16).Select(Function(b) b.ToString("X2")))`

Comment: So, how to convert a hexadecimal string to bytes? . | And how did you compare these Bytes with the Bytes of the file?

Comment: @Xenox (If you put @ username in a comment, that person gets notified.) Converting a hex string to a byte array is common enough that you can google for it (as I wrote in your earlier question). To compare the bytes, use the `=` operator on each element.

Comment: @AndrewMorton For example, according to the code I put above it would be something like this: **If I want to compare them, would it be like that?**
`'Bytes are those of the file.
'HexBytes is the hexadecimal string converted to Bytes.

if Bytes = HexBytes then

else

end if`

Comment: @Xenox No. What you need to do is check if bytes(0)=hexbytes(0). If it is, then check if bytes(1)=hexbytes(1). Continue for the length of the hexbytes array. If it is not equal, then check if bytes(1)=hexbytes(0). If it is, then check if bytes(2)=hexbytes(1). And so on.

Comment: @Xenox Or you might want to implement the [Boyer–Moore string-search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string-search_algorithm) (ignore that the name includes "string").